# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play, classnotfoundexception

I have android application. When I run or debug app on my eclipse it Works smoothly with 
no error no warnings.After then I get apk for Google play. Useres are getting below errors when they downloaded it from Google play market. Please help me I was not able to solve this problem. It can not find some classes.

This is errors which getting from developer console;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/versus/hit/yeni/JSONParser;
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signin$CheckUser.<init>(Signin.java:211)
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signin$2.onClick(Signin.java:121)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.versus.hit.yeni.JSONParser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.versus.hit.yeni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.versus.hit.yeni.JSONParser
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

---

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/versus/hit/yeni/JSONParser;
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signup.parseJson(Signup.java:384)
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signup.onCreateView(Signup.java:165)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.versus.hit.yeni.JSONParser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.versus.hit.yeni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 16 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.versus.hit.yeni.JSONParser
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

---

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/versus/hit/yeni/ACProgressFlower$Builder;
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signin$CheckUser.onPreExecute(Signin.java:236)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
    at com.versus.hit.yeni.Signin$2.onClick(Signin.java:123)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.versus.hit.yeni.ACProgressFlower$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.versus.hit.yeni-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib, system/vendor/lib/egl, system/lib/hw]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 14 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.versus.hit.yeni.ACProgressFlower$Builder
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

---

This is my manifest;

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.versus.hit.yeni"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.2.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >


          <activity android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.SplashActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
           <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>


             <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.MY_ACTION" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                 <data  android:scheme="versus" android:host="www.versushit.com" />


              </intent-filter>


    </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >


    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.SearchActivity"

           android:theme="@style/ACPLDialog" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.PersonalPage"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
           android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >

    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.FollowActivity"
           android:theme="@style/ACPLDialog" >

    </activity>


      <activity
        android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.ReportActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REPORT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


        <activity
        android:name="com.versus.hit.yeni.MailSender"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>



     <activity
        android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />




    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/appid" />

</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem

In my case it is happening because of instant run, Just disable it

Goto :

Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy -->  Instant run.

Comment: I do not see any called 'Instant run' option!! Where do I see this option?

Comment: which version of Android studio you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Please link your libs the correct way, your libraries are not compiled with your app, if you are using 3rd party libraries make sure you are copying them to the project when linking them. A screenshot of your linked libraries would help more.

Also on a side note, try to move to Android Studio its much better than Eclipse in handling libraries.

Answer (score 0):

it is saying -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.versus.hit.yeni.ACProgressFlower$Builder"
```

check what you are calling is it exist in bin folder on the same path or not if not try to add again same library as `@ahmad said` or clean the project and run again. 
`NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that the Class Loader  cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by changing

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

in build.gradle file. I'm not sure why this solved the problem. This may be a bug in the beta version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the app
2. restart your phone
3. reinstall the app

Answer (score 0):

Remove temporary **.gradle** folder from your Project folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens because I move the project location.
I remove the ".gradle " package of main module, then solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything on your project, but catch this issue, this you can try. Android is new to me, so when I get this issue I clear all files which auto generated include `.gradle`, `.build` and etc by android studio. It works! enjoy your coding!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `minifyEnabled true` in your gradle file in release buildTypes and `minifyEnabled false` in debug.

If so, try to add in your *proguard-rules.pro* file:

1. `-keep class com.versus.hit.yeni.ACProgressFlower$Builder`
2. `-keep class com.versus.hit.yeni.JSONParser`