# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, okhttp

I tried using OkHttp and Picasso ([following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/6291914)) for disk caching of images that I was downloading from Firebase storage. Now, the app gives exceptions and crashes. I have seen these posts: [post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134312/caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-class-not-found-using-the-boot-class), [post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430820/ava-lang-noclassdeffounderror-class-not-found-using-the-boot-class-loader-no-s) but I didn't find any relevant solutions. I also tried to clean and rebuild the project but had no luck.

Here is **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "social.com.networking.social.media.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'br.com.mauker.materialsearchview:materialsearchview:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.alirezaafkar:toolbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.3.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Full Stacktrace**:

```
Process: social.com.networking.social.media.app, PID: 28258
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:31)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:76)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:65)
at social.com.networkingsocialmediaapp.Global.onCreate(Global.java:17)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1018)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4991)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/social.com.networking.social.media.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/social.com.networking.social.media.app-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.defaultOkHttpClient(OkHttpDownloader.java:31)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:76)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:65)
at social.com.networkingsocialmediaapp.Global.onCreate(Global.java:17)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1018)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4991)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1555)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 15 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

**Edit 1:**
I have enabled MultiDex as Redman said but it still gives the same error. According to this: [developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep](http://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep), I need to decide which classes are necessary in the base APK. How do I determine which classes are necessary?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In *Android Studio 2.3 and higher*, There is **Instant Run** which may affect your code.

Disable `Instant Run`

*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run*

> In my case it was working perfect when run from `Android Studio` but
>   crashing when install from other sources

Answer (score 9):

1)Kindly uninstall the app from your mobile

2)Reinstall the app now from android studio

3)98% it will work else clean the project and reinstall it again

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!

Answer (score 7):

You may need to enable multidex, follow the guide from this

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html ,for enabling multidex

```
  defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21

    multiDexEnabled true
}

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```

Comment: i have enabled multidex as you said but still gives same error.according to this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#keep i need to decide which classes are necessary in base apk .how i determine which classes are necessary?

Comment: follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/31724082/6478047 this answer, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/37084656/6478047 this answer

Answer (score 4):

Just remove your project's build folder, then clean and run your application. This did the trick for me...

Answer (score 2):

My Code way compiling well on the device using USB cable, but when I was trying to install it using *.apk file it was breaking, so I unchecked the option *File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run*, but now its working fine with *.apk file and starting breaking with USB install, the error message is in the attachec image, even if I press OK it doesn't work, when I try yo install it again the same error message appears.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing **.gradle** folder from project.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  I am not using Android Studio to deploy, just commandline.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem, and it's still not possible to turn off the instant run.Later, I found that I deleted all the files under the build-cache folder, and then clean the project.My directory is C:\Users\ HDB . Android \ built-cache.I hope I can help other people who encounter this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs because of the differences in libraries' version specification that can lead to runtime errors.
Always use same versions of libraries in build.gradle.
For example:

Use this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

Instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem was solved by **Disable Instant Run**

Just go to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Disable the option

And restart the app

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is an old question, but I came here looking for a solution to a similar problem.)

I have a different answer to consider *before* you exhaust all the other suggestions above: **the ClassNotFoundException: YourParcelableClass error may not be the problem.**  In fact, it may not be *a* problem.

I have an app which displays a screen of various content which is passed in as a Parcelable and rendered as HTML in a WebView; it was working great until I cleaned up the code, checked it in, checked out a clean new tree, and uninstalled & reinstalled the app on my phone.  I started getting a blank screen; obviously that ClassNotFoundException in the log meant my content was not being unmarshalled correctly.

After *at least* an hour of disabling Instant Run, `rm -rf .gradle`, Clean Project, Invalidate Caches & Restart, etc., etc., I started adding increasingly sanity-questioning logging until I figured out that I *was* getting my content from `Intent.getParcelableExtra()`; the blank screen appeared to be unrelated!  (I still don't know why, but `WebView.loadData()` had stopped working, and had to be replaced with `WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL()`.)

Hopefully this saves someone else an hour of stupidity.  If you see that ClassNotFoundException with your class' name, check to see whether your objects are still being unmarshalled correctly; they might be!

Answer (score 0):

I found another "answer" to the issue.  I was getting the same error message using Android Studio 3.3.2.  I decided to clear ALL breakpoints.  On the breakpoints dialog there are two "permanant" options, Java Exception Breakpoints and Exception Breakpoints.   I had them both checked, by accident probably.   When I cleared them and other break points I could run under Debug mode. Now that debug is running I can add break points as long as those are not checked!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your app-level Gradle in android  tag

```
buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}
```